# Prevent notification when launching App

Tags: android, notifications

I have a `AlarmManager` in order to show notification. I don't want that I get a notification everytime I launch the app. I read a lot but nothing was satisfying. My method `doNotification` in `MainActivity.java` looks like this:

```
 public void doNotification(){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());  

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP ,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24*30 , pending); //every month
    }
```

This method is in the `OnCreate` of my `MainActivity` class.
I know, that this is the reason why I get a notification everytime I launch my app.

My goal was to fire a notification every month, starting from the Date where the app was launched the first time. E.g User launches app on 5. July then you will get a notification on every 5th of every month.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

**EDIT: According to the comments I used `SharedPreferences` is that a right use of it. Here is the new code:**

```
     public void doNotification(){
        boolean isFirstAlarm = getSharedPreferences("ALARMFIRSTTIME",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstAlarm",false);
        if(!isFirstAlarm) {

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, pending); //every month
        getSharedPreferences("ALARMFIRSTTIME", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putBoolean("isFirstAlarm",true)
                .apply();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Why would the *user* want this `Notification`? What is the value to the *user* of you forcing some UI on them one month after they first run your app? You are certainly welcome to use `add()` on `Calendar` to add a month and use `setWindow()` with `AlarmManager` to get control then, but only do this if the *user* wants it, as it is the *user's* device.

Comment: @CommonsWare thx for your comment. The reason of explaining why I fire a notification every month would be too much here. I just want it for severeal reasons. If I use add in `Calendar` don't I have to set a certain month? Because I want the notification every month. So I don't understand why  I should add a certain month? Could you please explain?

Comment: for it you have to keep store a boolean flag in shared preferences.
when apps open first time then set its value to true. 
and execute doNotification() only while boolean flag is false. after execution set boolean value to true.

Comment: @PawanSinghChauhan I edited my question with SharedPreferences, would you have a look, please ?

Comment: yes it is exact what i want to saying.

Comment: "So I don't understand why I should add a certain month?" -- you do not add a "certain" month. You add one month to the current time, to get a `Calendar` that is one month from now. You use `setWindow()` rather than `setInexactRepeating()`, because your repeat period is 30 days (which is not exactly a month for many months in many calendars) and you have no control over how inexact your alarm will be. You will also need to save the `Calendar` value somewhere, as it is very likely that your alarm will need to be re-created (e.g., after a reboot).

Comment: @CommonsWare I understood everything except saving a `Calendar` value. I know, using `SharedPreferences` is here the formular. But could you give a little code example for this issue? (Saving Calendar value)